# How can I get sublime text to run from the command line?

Tags: command-line

I am trying to get sublime text to run from the command line using this [tutorial](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html).

It says to run this command:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

But when I try to run that command I get an error "no such file or directory." Sublime text 2 is in my applications folder -- but it looks like there is no bin folder in my home directory. Do I need to create one? Is this something that should be there? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Yes simply create the `~/bin` directory and then create the link.  I doubt it should be there, but it's generally a best practice on Unix systems to create a `~/bin` to maintain extraneous executables that you'd like to use within your personal environment.

Additionally you'll need to make sure that this directory is also on your PATH (`echo $PATH`) so that you can execute this command from any location on your system, without have to explicitly call it out as:

```
$ ~/bin/subl
```

Comment: FWIW, on Mac OS X I use `~/.bin` so the directory doesn't appear in the Finder, since I'm only interested in those files from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way `open -a "sublime text" index.html`, you can create an alias in your shell profile configuration so it can be shorter `alias subl='open -a "sublime text"'`